# Running the same SQL script on different tables

Tags: mysql

I have a manually created conversion script that changes a product ID to another. It does it for a thousand products and I need to run it on 10 different tables. Can I do it without duplicating the script?

I hoped to do it like this, but it is not supported:

**convert_one.sql:**

```
UPDATE @table SET product_id=12345 where product_id=123
... a thousand similar lines
```

**convert_all.sql:**

```
SET @table = 'table1';
SOURCE convert_one.sql;

SET @table = 'table2';
SOURCE convert_one.sql;
```

Comment: Can you run your `SQL` code from some `php` script file

Comment: This is a Java app and a one-time conversion. Coding it is not efficient, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Otherwise your variable is simply treated like a string and you can't select from or update a string.

Try it like this:

```
SET @table = 'table1';
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('UPDATE ', @table, ' SET product_id=12345 where product_id=123;');
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```